# File not found if we check user permission in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

if we try to check permission or Add permission any user in my portal so we are getting Error

```
"File not found".
```

[image] 
[image]

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Can you post the SharePoint ULS log entries that correspond to the correlation ID shown in the error message?